# Ghostscript OCR and output file

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm try to apply OCR with Ghostscript to pdf file with this command

```
gswin64c -sOCRLanguage="fast/eng" -sDEVICE=pdfocr24 -o out.pdf in.pdf
```

Original PDF is 300DPI and Colored and **4.1MB**, but after run OCR, i have a PDF with **42.5MB**

I have tried to add -r300 -dDownScaleFactor=4 but these options decrease quality image and ocr accuracy.

Expected is to have a PDF a little bit large of original (same quality as original, but with OCR).

There are any advices for accomplish that?

Comment: That pdfocr devices render the content to an image, then run Tesseract over it to produce text. The text is then drawn over the image 'invisibly'. The act of rendering the file to an image will, obviously, make it larger. The pdfwrite device will, if Tesseract is built in, use it to try and determine Unicode code points for any text (that's real actual text, not images which happen to contain pictures of text) lacking a ToUnicode CMap. There is no support for any other kind of OCR, if you are looking to have OCR applied to an image contained within a PDF file, it can't do that.

Comment: Note that PDF files don't have a dpi. They may contain images which have an effective dpi when rendered but that is not quite the same thing. Without seeing the original I can't, of course, guess at why the output file is significantly larger, except that most likely the original is not simply a bitmap wrapped up in a PDF file.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks a lot four your time and clear answer.
I understood all process now.